# How to get more information about Android random restarts

Tags: reboot

Android randomly restarts - where would I find an error log or some other way of enabling information gathering from this process? I want to attempt to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 2):

Most logs are stored in catlog, you can use ADB (Android Debugging Bridge) to read it; there are [apps on the market](https://market.android.com/search?q=catlog&c=apps) can be used to read catlog.